# Server side sorting with backgrid

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backgrid

I'm doing a server side grid with [backgrid](http://backgridjs.com/), so every time I set any filter, it refresh with new data, also pagination.
But I have seen that when I click in a column header to sort a column, it doesn't fire any action to make the call to the server.

Do you if there is any way to implement that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What I did at the end was listen to the sort event and doing the calls by myself, then adding a blurry loader into my table did the trick